# JupyterHub throwing error while running jupyterhub command

Tags: jupyterhub

**Im getting following error while running jupyterhub command**
C:\Users\admin>jupyterhub
[I 2023-11-06 22:58:37.910 JupyterHub app:2859] Running JupyterHub version 4.0.2
[I 2023-11-06 22:58:37.910 JupyterHub app:2889] Using Authenticator: jupyterhub.auth.PAMAuthenticator-4.0.2
[I 2023-11-06 22:58:37.910 JupyterHub app:2889] Using Spawner: jupyterhub.spawner.SimpleLocalProcessSpawner-4.0.2
[I 2023-11-06 22:58:37.910 JupyterHub app:2889] Using Proxy: jupyterhub.proxy.ConfigurableHTTPProxy-4.0.2
[I 2023-11-06 22:58:37.910 JupyterHub app:1664] Loading cookie_secret from C:\Users\admin\jupyterhub_cookie_secret
[I 2023-11-06 22:58:37.957 JupyterHub proxy:556] Generating new CONFIGPROXY_AUTH_TOKEN
[E 2023-11-06 22:58:37.973 JupyterHub app:3382]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyterhub\app.py", line 3379, in launch_instance_async
await self.initialize(argv)
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyterhub\app.py", line 2906, in initialize
await self.init_users()
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyterhub\app.py", line 1933, in init_users
if self.authenticator.enable_auth_state:
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 688, in **get**
return t.cast(G, self.get(obj, cls))  # the G should encode the Optional
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 636, in get
default = obj.trait_defaults(self.name)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1900, in trait_defaults
return t.cast(Sentinel, self._get_trait_default_generator(names[0])(self))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\traitlets\traitlets.py", line 1243, in **call**
return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyterhub\app.py", line 1144, in _authenticator_default
return self.authenticator_class(parent=self, _deprecated_db_session=self.db)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyterhub\auth.py", line 1056, in **init**
raise *pamela_error from None
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\jupyterhub\auth.py", line 16, in 
import pamela
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\pamela.py", line 60, in 
LIBPAM = CDLL(find_library("pam"))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\ctypes_*init**.py", line 369, in **init**
if '/' in name or '\' in name:
^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable

How to resolve this issue an run without any errors